# How to create multiple dataframe from a excel data table

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have extracted this data frame from an excel spreadsheet using pandas library,
after getting the needed columns and,
I have table formatted like this,

```
    REF PLAYERS
0   103368  Andrés Posada Sanmiguel
1   300552  Diego Posada Sanmiguel
2   103304  Roberto Motta Stanziola
3   NaN NaN
4   REF PLAYERS
5   1047012 ANABELLA EISMANN DE AMAYA
6   104701  FERNANDO ENRIQUE AMAYA CASTRO
7   103451  AUGUSTO ANTONIO ALVARADO AZCARRAGA
8   103484  Kevin Adrian Villarreal Kam
9   REF PLAYERS
10  NaN NaN
11  NaN NaN
12  NaN NaN
13  NaN NaN
14  REF PLAYERS
15  NaN NaN
16  NaN NaN
17  NaN NaN
18  NaN NaN
19  REF PLAYERS
```

I want to create multiple dataframes converting each row [['REF', 'PLAYERS']] to a new dataframe columns.
suggestions are welcomed I also need to preserve the blank spaces. A pandas newbie.

Comment: Based on this example, do you want to have 20 empty dataframes with rows as column names. Am I right?

Comment: yes, that's what I'm looking for.

Comment: This can be done comparing the row value to the "REF", "PLAYERS", then groupby on the cumcount. I need few minutes.

Comment: so each dataframe should just have 1 row? the REF and the PLAYER?

Comment: each dataframe will have 2 columns, 4 rows. the empty values should be intact.

Comment: I got this trying your method. AttributeError: '_io.BufferedRandom' object has no attribute 'groupby'

Comment: @Martins there was a typo in my code, variable "temp" that don't exist. It should be fine now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this to work, you must first read the dataframe from the file differently: set the argument `header=None` in your `pd.read_excel()` function. Because now your columns are called "REF" and "PLAYERS", but we would like to group by them.

Then the first column name probably would be "0", and the first line will be as follows, where the `df` is the name of your dataframe:

```
# Set unique index for each group
df["group_id"] = (df[0] == "REF").cumsum()
```

Solution:

```
# Set unique index for each group
df["group_id"] = (df["name_of_first_column"] == "REF").cumsum()

# Iterate over groups
dataframes = []
for name, group in df.groupby("group_id"):
    df_ = group
    # promote 1st row to column name
    df_.columns = df_.iloc[0]
    # and drop it
    df_ = df_.iloc[1:]
    # drop index column
    df_ = df_[["REF", "PLAYERS"]]
    # append to the list of dataframes
    dataframes.append(df_)
```

All your multiple dataframes are now stored in an array `dataframes`.

Comment: This Works, I will have to do some tweaking to it.

Answer (score 1):

You can split your `dataframe`, into equal lengths (in your case 4 rows for each `df`), using `np.split`.

Since you want 4 rows per dataframe, you can split it into 5 different `df`:

```
import numpy as np
dfs = [df.loc[idx] for idx in np.split(df.index,5)]
```

---

And then create your individual dataframes:

```
df1 = dfs[1]
df1

                                  REF PLAYERS
4                                 REF PLAYERS
5           1047012 ANABELLA EISMANN DE AMAYA
6       104701  FERNANDO ENRIQUE AMAYA CASTRO
7  103451  AUGUSTO ANTONIO ALVARADO AZCARRAGA


df2 = dfs[2]
df2
                            REF PLAYERS
8   103484  Kevin Adrian Villarreal Kam
9                           REF PLAYERS
10                              NaN NaN
11                              NaN NaN
```

Comment: Yes, this will also work, if only there are always 4 rows per dataframe, as in the given expamle.

Comment: I thought that is what you're after?